# Trying to make Weborb .NET work with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, weborb

We have been using weborb for .net on an existing application for some time now and it has worked very well. We decided to rewrite our application in ASP.NET MVC and now I need to make weborb work with mvc. I have been getting a 404 the resource cannot be found error while trying to connect to the weborb.aspx page. I have added all of the appropriate entries to the web.config file and I even found this article explaining how to make the two work together

http://aspzone.com/tech/how-to-get-weborb-and-asp-net-mvc-to-work-together/

But to no avail. I can't make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had the project set up incorrectly as a website and not an mvc application. Once I did that the route explained the blog post I referenced worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If 404 is given then there is no such resource. Most likely the MVC tries to route the request and cannot find appropriate one.

Try to add ignore route in the beginning of routes registration. Something like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("weborb.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```